# Efficient generation of a 3D mesh to solve a diffusion PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, mesh, finite-element-method

I'm new to FEM and trying to figure out what is the most efficient way of generating a mesh and solving an equation. As a warm-up to the particular problem I'm interested in, I want to calculate the evolution of the temperature profile in a gas flow within a reactor shell with two cooling tubes maintained at a given temperature.

i defined the region like this :

```
<< NDSolve`FEM` 
{reactorLength,shellID, tubeOD}={6.0, 0.5, 0.03};
tubeRegion = 
 RegionUnion[
 Cylinder[{{0, -0.25*shellID, 
 0}, {0, -0.25*shellID, +reactorLength}}, 1 tubeOD], 
 Cylinder[{{0, 0.25*shellID, 0}, {0, 0.25*shellID, +reactorLength}}, 
 1 tubeOD]];
tubeSection = 
RegionUnion[Disk[{0, -0.25*shellID}, 1 tubeOD], 
Disk[{0, +0.25*shellID}, 1 tubeOD]];
region = RegionDifference[
Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, +reactorLength}}, shellID], tubeRegion];
```

So we have a large shell with two tubes in the middle. Next I generate a mesh:

```
regionmesh = 
ToElementMesh[region, "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.05/10]
```

And the equation to be solved :

```
equation = 
D[t[x, y, z], z] == 
D[t[x, y, z], {x, 2}] + D[t[x, y, z], {y, 2}] + 
NeumannValue[
10*(150 - t[x, y, z]), Element[{x, y, z}, tubeRegion]]
```

With the initial value:

```
dirichlet=DirichletCondition[
t[x, y, z] == 
170, Element[{x, y},
RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, shellID], tubeSection] && z == 0]]
```

The equation is then solved:

```
solmesh = 
NDSolveValue[{equation, dirichlet}, 
t, Element[{x, y, z}, regionmesh]];
```

The procedure works but the mesh does not look like it accurately reproduces the tube region. Besides, I'm specifying the initial value of the temeprature in a way that seems inconsistent with the mesh. I think it would be better if I could directly specify it on the mesh itself rather than having to specify a geometric section. Any suggestions to make this code more efficient ?

Comment: What is `tube0D`?

Comment: @user21 Added the missing parameter :)

Comment: Wouldn't use MMA for this problem. Just my opinion :)

Comment: @Valacar Well, that's what I have avaiable for use so :)

Comment: Still struggling to improve this code. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is to generate a 2D mesh and the extrude the 3D version from it.

```
mr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[Disk[], tubeSection]
  (*,AccuracyGoal -> 3,PrecisionGoal -> 4*)]
```

[image]

Make a region product with a line:

```
rp = RegionProduct[mr, Line[{{0}, {reactorLength}}]]
```

[image]

And then you can generate a FEM mesh from it if you want:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[rp];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Note, that even though this is a second order mesh, the boundary faces will not be curved.